# How to Create iOS Facebook Post With Tagged/Linked Place

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, fbsdk

My question should be pretty simple. Using the Facebook iOS SDK, how do I allow a user to create a new post and then link a business location to their post? It seems like it would be pretty simple but I've ended up going in circles for hours trying to figure out the Facebook Open Graph.

I tried to use a FBSDKShareLinkContent object and filling out a place id but when the post shows up in the timeline, there is no location attached to the post.

```
FBSDKShareLinkContent *content = [[FBSDKShareLinkContent alloc] init];
content.contentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://foo.com"];
content.contentTitle= @"Love Place";
content.contentDescription=@"I love this place";
content.placeID = @"166403937438";

[FBSDKShareDialog showFromViewController:self withContent:content delegate:self];
```

Once I dove into FBSDKShareOpenGraphObject it seemed like I was no longer creating a simple user post with a message. Those all seemed to involve story actions like "read a book" or "went on a run".

All I want to do is post a message that tags the message location to a place id.